# How to register a listener on a OID / Managed Object using SNMP4J to act on set or get requests the agent receives?

Tags: java, snmp4j

I need to implement a basic `snmp` agent into my application. This agent should be able to answer get and set requests from `snmp` browsers on my own `OID's`. Since most examples for `snmp4j` are quite old and use the "extend the `org.snmp4j.agent.BaseAgent.classapproach"` there are of little use.

Therefore tried to understand and strip down the `org.snmp4j.agent.example.SampleAgentincluded` inside the `snmp4j-agent-3.2.1.jar`. I managed to get an example working with just the mandatory MIB's ( i at least think they are required because the source of the `AgentConfigManager` states in a comment they are mandatory **snmpv2MIB, snmpMpdMib, targetMIB, communityMIB, notificationMIB, frameworkMIB, usmMIB, vacmMIB, tlsTmMib** ) provided by the sample config file.

I than added a custom `OID` to query to the agend using the following code

```java
    MOServer server = new DefaultMOServer();
    MOServer[] moServers = new MOServer[]{server};
    ...
    AgentConfigManager agent = new AgentConfigManager(new OctetString(MPv3.createLocalEngineID()),
                    messageDispatcher,
                    null,
                    moServers,
                    ThreadPool.create("SampleAgent", 3),
                    configurationFactory, 
                    new DefaultMOPersistenceProvider(moServers, configFile),
                    new EngineBootsCounterFile(bootCounterFile), null, dhKickstartParameters);
    ...
    agent.initialize();
    ...

    server.register(new MOScalar(new OID("1.someIODshere.0"), MOAccessImpl.ACCESS_READ_ONLY, new OctetString("object 1")), null);
```

Now i'm missing a way to intercept get or set requests from `snmp` managers / browsers to return a dynamic value or change the program behavior according to the request.

I kind of expect to be able to bind a kind of event listener to this `OID` to get notified on requests / changes.

How to watch an `OID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. I was looking at the wrong place. I thought a had to add a listener to the agent, but instead i have to add the listener to the server.

```
server.addLookupListener(new MOServerLookupListener() {
    @Override
    public void lookupEvent(MOServerLookupEvent event) {
        System.out.println();
        ((MOScalar)event.getLookupResult()).setValue(new OctetString(new Date().toString()));
    }
    @Override
    public void queryEvent(MOServerLookupEvent event) {
        System.out.println();
    }
},moScalar);
```

I can now react to the requests. YAY!